# How to stop GridView Builder refreshing the widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-build

I am trying to get rid of this blinking/flashing of the widget presented in the image below. This is an Alert Dialog opened. Below it's a *GridView Builder* which creates images. The images are refreshing when I am trying to drag and resize the height of the container. I know *setState* it's called multiple times, but it doesn't matter, the widget should be immutable.

I changed the *Grid View* to a *Stateless Widget*, after trying a while using *AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin*, *wantToKeepAlive*, but nothing is changing.

[image]

```
class GridViewBuilderOutiftTabTapped extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<CleverCloset> myClassVar;
  const GridViewBuilderOutiftTabTapped(this.myClassVar);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
        physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
          crossAxisSpacing: 5,
          mainAxisSpacing: 5,
          maxCrossAxisExtent: SizeConfig.screenWidth!/4,),
        itemCount: myClassVar.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
          return InkWell(
            onTap: (){
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
              ),
              width: SizeConfig.screenWidth!/4,
              height: SizeConfig.screenWidth!/4,
              child: FittedBox(
                child:
                FadeInImage(
                  placeholder: const AssetImage('assets/placeholder.gif'),
                  image: CleverCloset.imageFromBase64String(myClassVar[index].getImage!).image,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
}

void addOutfitPlannerDialog(BuildContext context) async{
    await showGeneralDialog(
        barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
        transitionBuilder: (context, a1, a2, widget) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Transform.scale(
          scale: a1.value,
          child: Opacity(
          opacity: a1.value,
            child: AlertDialog(
            actionsPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
            titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
            buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            title: _getBackAndSaveButtons(context),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            content: SizedBox(
              width: 100.w,
              height: 100.h,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                      height: 82.h,
                      color: const Color(0xff393432),
                      child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(45, 8, 45, 10.h),
                    color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    child: StatefulBuilder(
                      builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                    return Container(
                      height: heightBottomOutfitPlanner,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border: Border(
                          top: BorderSide( //                    <--- top side
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      width: 100.w,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 100.w,
                            height: 8.h,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex:7,
                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                      itemCount: outfitPlanerOrganizerEntriesList.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                        return InkWell(
                                          onTap: (){
                                            getOutfitPlannerTabTappedImages(outfitPlanerOrganizerEntriesList[index], setState);
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
                                            decoration: (outfitPlanerOrganizerEntriesList[index]==myOutfitPlannerTabTappedImages[0].closetOrganizer) || (outfitPlanerOrganizerEntriesList[index]=="To Buy" && myOutfitPlannerTabTappedImages[0].closetOrganizer==null) ? const BoxDecoration(
                                              border: Border(
                                                bottom: BorderSide( //                    <--- top side
                                                  color: Color(0xffE4BCB4),
                                                  width: 3.0,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ):null,
                                            child: Center(child: Text(outfitPlanerOrganizerEntriesList[index],
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                ))),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(width: 30),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex:1,
                                  child: Container(
                                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                        border: Border(
                                          left: BorderSide( //                    <--- top side
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            width: 1.0,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                        onPanStart:(details) => _handleDrag(details, setState),
                                        onPanUpdate:(details) => _handleUpdate(details, setState),
                                        child: const Icon(Icons.drag_indicator,
                                          size: 35,
                                        ),
                                      )

                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 5),
                          !isLoadingOutfitPlannerTabTappedImages ? Container(
                            width: 100.w,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
                            height: heightBottomOutfitPlanner-10.h,
                            child: GridViewBuilderOutiftTabTapped(myOutfitPlannerTabTappedImages),
                          ) : Container(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )


          ),

            ),
          ),
        );
    },
    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
    barrierDismissible: true,
    barrierLabel: '',
    context: context,
    pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {return Container();}
    );
  }
```